# List files in a path which having wildcards using DirectoryScanner

Tags: java, apache, ant, wildcard

Im using apache directory scanner to scan files in a path having wildcards.

```
DirectoryScanner scanner = new DirectoryScanner();
scanner.setIncludes(new String[]{"*/*.java"});
scanner.setBasedir("C:/Temp");
scanner.setCaseSensitive(false);
scanner.scan();
String[] files = scanner.getIncludedFiles();
```

The problem here is if i use the above code it will only display java files inside sub directories of Temp and not java files which are directly in Temp folder.

Also I have notice if i use `(new String[]{"*.java"})` then it will list all the java files in Temp folder and `(new String[]{"**/*.java"})` will list all the java files even inside sub directories of sub directory. So my question here is,

1) Is this the standard wild card syntax that apply for every where? i mean **/ means all directories and */ means only sub directories?

2)How to get files which are in Temp directory directly and inside sub directoroes only (not again inside those sub directories like we use **)

3)Now we can see when using DirectoryScanner  we have base directory and then the relavanat wildcard syntax. **But suppose we have wildcards in middle of the base directoy too**. If so how can we use the DirectoryScanner?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
scanner.setIncludes(new String[]{"*/*.java", "*.java"});
```

Add every needed wildcard to this array.
Is there a special reason why you're using the DirectoryScanner? Using a self-written recursive function for that seems easier.

See http://leepoint.net/notes-java/io/10file/20recursivelist.html

Comment: thanks chzbrgla..just wanna know if thats the wildcard standard using */ to list files in sub directories etc. If so i can go ahead with Directory Scanner because it will give the result according to the wildcard standard given

Comment: I don't think there is a real standard for wildcards. To be quite honest I have never used DirectoryScanner since this is such a trivial task that can easily be achieved by writing a recursive function. My answer was merely derived from the code snippet you provided - please vote if it was helpful :p